# How to get subregions of same values in 2D boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, boolean

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Hello, I'm trying to find a way in python to extract the indices of a boolean array where sections have the same value or are contiguous.

[image: Contained Sections]

Ideally I'd want the indices of each of the highlighted sections.

Comment: Maybe `np.where(m)`?

Comment: You may get better answer when you explain what you have tried and where you stuck.

Comment: If you want the *individual* sections, and not just all locations of ones, might be worth looking at `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`

Answer (score 1):

That's connected component analysis which has been answered before. Here is a modified possible solution for you.

```
    import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label


    def analysis(array):
        labeled, _ = label(array, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.int))
        for i in np.arange(1, np.max(labeled)+1):
            pixels = np.array(np.where(labeled == i))
            x1 = np.min(pixels[1, :])
            x2 = np.max(pixels[1, :])
            y1 = np.min(pixels[0, :])
            y2 = np.max(pixels[0, :])
            print(str(i) + ' | slice: array[' + str(y1) + ':' + str(y2) + ', ' + str(x1) + ':' + str(x2) + ']')
    
    
    example1 = np.array([
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    ]).astype(bool)
   
    
    for a in [example1]:
        print(a, '\n')
        analysis(a)
```

That's the output (without the example):

```
[[...]] 

1 | slice: array[1:2, 3:5]
2 | slice: array[4:6, 6:8]
3 | slice: array[8:8, 2:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
teste = ([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

for x in range(len(teste)):
    for y in range(len(teste[x])):
        if teste[x][y] == 1:
            print('ROW: ' + str(x) + ' COL: ' + str(y) + ' IS: ' + str(teste[x][y]))
```

output:

```
ROW: 0 COL: 0 IS: 1
ROW: 0 COL: 1 IS: 1
ROW: 0 COL: 4 IS: 1
ROW: 1 COL: 0 IS: 1
ROW: 2 COL: 2 IS: 1
ROW: 2 COL: 3 IS: 1
ROW: 2 COL: 4 IS: 1
ROW: 3 COL: 3 IS: 1
ROW: 3 COL: 4 IS: 1
ROW: 4 COL: 0 IS: 1
ROW: 4 COL: 2 IS: 1
ROW: 4 COL: 3 IS: 1
```